# Write to multiple DB in single transaction in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, transactions, hibernate-session

I have a requirement where i need to write to multiple DB. If any exception occurs while writing to anyone of the DBs, i want to rollback everything.

E.G.

```
Session userSession= a.getUserDBSession();
Session departmentSession= a.getDepartmentSession();
Session carSession= a.getCarSession();

//Do some work and write to User DB
// Do some work and write to Department DB
//Do some work and write to Car DB
// commit everything.
```

Note: Session is Hibernate Session
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Atomikos with hibernate.

Check the below link.

http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/HibernateThreeStandalone